# Issue with async and await in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Calling Method:

```
internal object ExecuteJob(RequestParam inputParam)
{
    bool jobStatus = false;
    var result = jobManager.ExecuteJob(inputParam);
    // Code continues

}
```

Invoking Method:

```
public async Task<int> ExecuteJob(RequestParam param)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        result = package.Execute();
        jobResult = (int)result;
    });

    return jobResult;
}
```

Once package got completed, it should return back to the calling method, How can we achieve this? Because inside await, I couldn't able to use return like below,

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    result = package.Execute();
    jobResult = (int)result;
    if(result ==  ssisruntime.DTSExecResult.Success)
        return jobResult;
});
```

Please someone help.

Comment: Maybe this? `return await Task.Run(() => { ... return jobResult;}`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It didn't work, Tried this earlier.

Comment: What is the problem? What is happening when you compile and\or run this code?

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type void to int

Comment: And if `result` is not equal to `ssisruntime.DTSExecResult.Success` ?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like this:

```
internal async Task<object> ExecuteJobAsync(RequestParam inputParam)
{
    bool jobStatus = false;

    var result = await jobManager.ExecuteJob(inputParam);
    // Code continues
}

public Task<int> ExecuteJob(RequestParam param)
{
     return Task.Run<int>(() =>
     {
         return (int)package.Execute();
     });
}
```

Comment: The return type of an async method must be `void` or `Task` or `Task<T>`. It could not be `object`.

Comment: @S.Akbari Thanks for the hint. I've edited my answer

Comment: Package execution should be asynchronous. But i couldn't able to see from your code. Please let me know.